# Using Command Line how to make the user an Administrator

Tags: macos, command-line, administrator

As soon I bind a Mac to the AD Domain, I usually log into the Mac with the user account.

Of course, under System Preference, User & Groups, the user account is marked as: Managed, Mobile

My second step, is to make the user an Administrator account because I want to allow him/her to install/remove stuff from her/his Mac.

So, with the GUI, System Preferences > Users & Groups > I select the user name and I check mark the option: enable Allow user to administer this computer and I restart the machine and everything works fine.  The user now is an Admin for that machine.

Question, how do I perform the above process with the command line in Terminal?  Not the bind process, but to make the user Admin for that specific machine.

Answer (score 13):

```
sudo dscl . -merge /Groups/admin GroupMembership username
```

where ‘username’ is the username of the user you would like to make an admin.

`sudo` since making changes like this requires elevated privileges.
`dscl` is the Directory Service command line utility.
`.` is the local machine.
`-merge` allows you to add a new key to a record path.
`/Groups/admin` is the record path for the key.
`GroupMembership` is the key you would like to assign a value.
`username` is the value for the key.